# SQL optimisation

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have this query on my database, it's basically pulling the ones that is within 10 miles radius from the coordinate.

```
SELECT id 
  FROM business 
 WHERE  ( coordinates!='' 
   AND getDistance('-2.1032155,49.1801863', coordinates)<10 ) 
   AND id NOT IN ('6', '4118') ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 0,5
```

when I profile this query, I get this:
JOIN SIZE: 3956 (BAD)
USING TEMPORARY (BAD)
USINGI FILESORT (BAD)

Can you guys help me optimising this query?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will always need FILESORT (sorting the resulting data in temporary memory) as you "order by" something that is not indexed (rand()).

Depending on the optimizing capabilities of your DBMS, you might be better of using "AND id != '6' AND id != '4118'" instead of a "NOT IN" clause.

You should always state the fixed information first in queries, although this depends on the capabilities of the query optimizer as well. Also, the criteria should align with an index, meaning that the order of appearance of criteria should be the same as in the index you want your DMBS to use. There's usually an option to state which index to use (the keyword is "Index hint"), but most DMBS know best what index to use in most cases anway (guessing from the query itself).

And you will never get around USING TEMPORARY while you are using a criterium that is generated at query runtime (your function).

Comment: I always use IN() to check subset of the condition. Is this a bad exercise? for example, if I want to calculate something that member has on his favorite, I would do: SELECT * FROM table WHERE member_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, ... 2000)

Comment: Take my statement with a grain of salt. This heavily depends on the capabilities of the specific DMBS. If the query optimizer is clever it can easily unwind IN statements into the corresponding "field = 'value' OR ..." statements. But I've seen DBMSes that fail in that regard; and functions run on every record before it is reported back to the overlaying layer make queries slow.